# Why is Tailwind css not work on my Windows?

Tags: python, node.js, github, solidity

I am new to this software and just trying to install a `package.json`. When everything is set to go I of course hit `npm start` but receive this error regarding tailwind:

```
PS C:\Users\test> npm start

> webapp-v2@3.0.4 start C:\Users\test
> TAILWIND_MODE=watch craco start

'TAILWIND_MODE' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! webapp-v2@3.0.4 start: `TAILWIND_MODE=watch craco start`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the webapp-v2@3.0.4 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\test\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2021-10-17T21_20_30_378Z-debug.log
```

I researched and found that a solution could be to install `npm install postcss postcss-cli`
When entering this I receive:

```
> node-hid@0.7.9 install C:\Users\test\node_modules\node-hid
> prebuild-install || node-gyp rebuild

prebuild-install WARN install No prebuilt binaries found (target=14.17.5 runtime=node arch=x64 libc= platform=win32)

C:\Users\test\node_modules\node-hid>if not defined npm_config_node_gyp (node "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\node-gyp-bin\\..\..\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" rebuild )  else (node "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" rebuild )       
gyp ERR! find Python 
gyp ERR! find Python Python is not set from command line or npm configuration
gyp ERR! find Python Python is not set from environment variable PYTHON
gyp ERR! find Python checking if "python" can be used
gyp ERR! find Python - "python" is not in PATH or produced an error
gyp ERR! find Python checking if "python2" can be used
gyp ERR! find Python - "python2" is not in PATH or produced an error
gyp ERR! find Python checking if "python3" can be used
gyp ERR! find Python - "python3" is not in PATH or produced an error
gyp ERR! find Python checking if the py launcher can be used to find Python 2
gyp ERR! find Python - "py.exe" is not in PATH or produced an error
gyp ERR! find Python checking if Python is C:\Python27\python.exe
gyp ERR! find Python - "C:\Python27\python.exe" could not be run
gyp ERR! find Python checking if Python is C:\Python37\python.exe
gyp ERR! find Python - "C:\Python37\python.exe" could not be run
gyp ERR! find Python 
gyp ERR! find Python **********************************************************
gyp ERR! find Python You need to install the latest version of Python.
gyp ERR! find Python Node-gyp should be able to find and use Python. If not,
gyp ERR! find Python you can try one of the following options:
gyp ERR! find Python - Use the switch --python="C:\Path\To\python.exe"
gyp ERR! find Python   (accepted by both node-gyp and npm)
gyp ERR! find Python - Set the environment variable PYTHON
gyp ERR! find Python - Set the npm configuration variable python:
gyp ERR! find Python   npm config set python "C:\Path\To\python.exe"
gyp ERR! find Python For more information consult the documentation at:
gyp ERR! find Python https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp#installation
gyp ERR! find Python **********************************************************
gyp ERR! find Python 
gyp ERR! configure error
gyp ERR! stack Error: Could not find any Python installation to use
gyp ERR! stack     at PythonFinder.fail (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-python.js:307:47)
gyp ERR! stack     at PythonFinder.runChecks (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-python.js:136:21)
gyp ERR! stack     at PythonFinder.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-python.js:225:16)
gyp ERR! stack     at PythonFinder.execFileCallback (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-python.js:271:16)
gyp ERR! stack     at exithandler (child_process.js:397:5)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.errorhandler (child_process.js:409:5)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:400:28)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:275:12)
gyp ERR! stack     at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:467:16)
gyp ERR! stack     at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:82:21)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.19043
gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd C:\Users\test\node-hid
gyp ERR! node -v v14.17.5
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v5.1.0
npm WARN @babel/plugin-bugfix-v8-spread-parameters-in-optional-chaining@7.15.4 requires a peer of @babel/core@^7.13.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN postcss-browser-comments@3.0.0 requires a peer of browserslist@^4 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN postcss-cli@9.0.1 requires a peer of postcss@^8.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN postcss-reporter@7.0.4 requires a peer of postcss@^8.1.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@2.3.2 (node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@2.3.2: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.13 (node_modules\webpack-dev-server\node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.13: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.13 (node_modules\watchpack-chokidar2\node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.13: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: node-hid@0.7.9 (node_modules\node-hid):
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: node-hid@0.7.9 install: `prebuild-install || node-gyp rebuild`
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Exit status 1

+ postcss-cli@9.0.1
+ postcss@7.0.39
added 1 package from 1 contributor and updated 3 packages in 80.336s

257 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details
```

However, when I then `npm start` again I receive the same tailwind error code. Any help would be fantastic thank you.

Thank you for your time.

Kind regards,
N.

Comment: Post your package.json. You try to set a environment variable, under windows this has to be indicated with `set`, e.g. `set ENV_NAME=value`

Comment: Hi Marc cheers for the reply - I'll have to send the package.json in sections due to character limit.

Comment: {
  "name": "webapp-v2",
  "version": "3.0.4",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@0x/contract-addresses": "^6.3.0",
    "@0x/protocol-utils": "^1.7.2",
    "@craco/craco": "^6.1.2",
    "@headlessui/react": "^1.3.0",
    "@popperjs/core": "^2.9.3",
    "@reduxjs/toolkit": "^1.5.1",
    "@tailwindcss/forms": "^0.3.3",
    "@types/jest": "^26.0.15",
    "@types/lodash": "^4.14.170",
    "@types/node": "^12.0.0",
    "@types/react": "^17.0.0",
    "@types/react-dom": "^17.0.0",
    "@types/react-redux": "^7.1.16",
    "@types/react-router-dom": "^5.1.7",

Comment: "@web3-react/core": "^6.1.9",
    "@web3-react/fortmatic-connector": "^6.1.6",
    "@web3-react/frame-connector": "^6.0.9",
    "@web3-react/injected-connector": "^6.0.7",
    "@web3-react/lattice-connector": "^6.1.9",
    "@web3-react/ledger-connector": "^6.1.9",
    "@web3-react/network-connector": "^6.1.9",
    "@web3-react/portis-connector": "^6.1.9",
    "@web3-react/torus-connector": "^6.1.9",
    "@web3-react/trezor-connector": "^6.1.9",
    "@web3-react/walletconnect-connector": "^6.2.4",
    "@web3-react/walletlink-connector": "^6.2.3",
    "axios": "^0.21.1",

Comment: "bignumber.js": "^9.0.1",
    "cypress": "^8.0.0",
    "dayjs": "^1.10.5",
    "eth-multicall": "^1.4.0",
    "json-bigint": "^1.0.0",
    "lightweight-charts": "^3.5.0",
    "lodash": "^4.17.21",
    "numbro": "^2.3.5",
    "numeral": "^2.0.6",
    "postcss-cli": "^9.0.1",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-device-detect": "^1.17.0",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-intl": "^5.17.6",
    "react-popper": "^2.2.5",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "4.0.3",
    "react-table": "^7.7.0",
    "rxjs": "6.6.7",

Comment: "source-map-explorer": "^2.5.2",
    "use-async-effect": "^2.2.3",
    "web-vitals": "^1.0.1",
    "web3": "^1.5.0"
  },

Comment: "devDependencies": {
    "@types/json-bigint": "^1.0.0",
    "@types/numeral": "^2.0.1",
    "@types/react-table": "^7.7.2",
    "autoprefixer": "^9",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^8.3.0",
    "eslint-loader": "^4.0.2",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^3.4.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.23.2",
    "husky": "^6.0.0",
    "lint-staged": "^11.0.0",
    "postcss": "^7.0.39",
    "prettier": "^2.3.0",
    "react-redux": "^7.2.4",
    "tailwindcss": "npm:@tailwindcss/postcss7-compat@2.2.4",
    "typescript": "^4.1.2"
  },

Comment: "scripts": {
    "analyze": "source-map-explorer 'build/static/js/*.js'",
    "start": "TAILWIND_MODE=watch craco start",
    "build": "craco build",
    "test": "craco test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "husky": {
    "hooks": {
      "pre-commit": "lint-staged"
    }
  },
  "lint-staged": {
    "src/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx,json,css,scss,md}": [
      "prettier --write"
    ]
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ],

Comment: "rules": {
      "@typescript-eslint/no-unused-vars": 0
    }
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}

Comment: Please let me know if you need it layed out better Marc - I tried crtl+K but nothing happens to change the format

Comment: Dude... Please take a moment and complete the tour: https://stackoverflow.com/tour, read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and post a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), [how to edit my question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit)